# App with multiple analytic frameworks - should i use vistorPattern

Tags: design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I realize pre-mature optimization is evil. But in my app we have many analytics and crash reporting third party tools. they have been spread out over code throughout.  We are using Answers,Crashlytics, newRelic,Kochava, adobe analytics, etc etc. Would it be better to use a visitor Pattern and make each one of these a visitor and then make all the java files using these visible ? I'd like a clean way to break separate this code away from the business logic. How would i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts for the problem,

1. How to keep your code clean without having to deal with all clutter added by integrating third party tools
2. How to call the relevant tool for the relevant event (e.g. crash reporter should not be called for screen view)

To address these concerns, you could create 2 services (may be more based on functionality)

```
class IAnalyticsService {
    void PageView(DetailsDto dto);
    //TODO add other necessary methods
}

ICrashReporterService {
    void Crashed(ErrorDto dto);
    //TODO add other necessary methods
}
```

Now you could implement visitor pattern for each third party service you want to use inside the implementation of these services.